# index rebuild/reorganize frequency

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, index, maintenance, fragmentation

I am a dba by accident. I am doing index  rebuild/reorganize. I would love to use some scripts once I become comfortable doing these tasks. I did go through some of the forum pages regarding this topic. I have a sql server 2008R2 instance which has around 25 databases of different size and needs. I have been assigned to do index tuning for 8 databases. Since the size and the fragmentation level and the no of indexes and also the rate at which de-fragmentation happens differs from database to database, I understand that some databases need an index maintenance on a monthly basis and few others on a weekly basis. I have two questions:

*How frequently should I schedule for the rebuild/reorganize process?*
For eg: Last month I rebuilt indexes for fragment level above 30% and reorganized and updated stats for 5-30% fragment level. Then I checked it after a week, i found one or two fragmented indexes, I checked it after a month and I found roughly around 10 fragmented indexes..is it the right time to schedule for an index maintenance again?

*If I develop a common script for the instance, how should I make it work for all the databases on the instance, because not every database would need an index maintenance at the same time.*

Comment: Looks like you are getting the same recommendation from everyone in the first 3 answers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. Do I need to always restart the application servers after index and statistics maintenance?

Comment: No that is not necessary.

Answer (score 5):

Don't re-invent the wheel; just get a solution like Ola's in place now:

- [Ola Hallengren's SQL Server Backup, Integrity Check, and Index and Statistics Maintenance](https://ola.hallengren.com/)

You can tweak the settings and learn how it works over time.

Comment: I guess all three of you gave same answer ? But no body specifically told him about frequency and I guess answer would be it depends you need to use script and evaluate yourself the frequency

Comment: @Shanky The defaults are pretty reasonable, and this is what I meant by "tweak the settings and learn how it works over time."

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use Ola Hallengren's scripts, freely available and widely used.

His website is: https://ola.hallengren.com/

```
•DatabaseBackup: SQL Server Backup

•DatabaseIntegrityCheck: SQL Server Integrity Check

•IndexOptimize: SQL Server Index and Statistics Maintenance
```

He has the best practices coded into his scripts, so it should serve you well.

EDIT: For my servers I have found that once a week works fine for us.

With regard to the databases on your server, you can run separate jobs, or you can have a single job go through all the databases.  Look at the MaintenanceSolution to see how to  include and exclude databases.

Comment: This does not answer OP question he is asking about how frequently he should rebuild indexes.

Comment: @Shanky - Edited

Answer (score 1):

You can't go wrong with Ola Hallengren's award winning solution. It's pretty awesome ;

https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html

You can schedule this to run once a day to begin with, and then you should re-evaluate your needs based on how busy the solution actually becomes regarding the needed index maintenance on your particular system.